# org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair in post method

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm writing some code like :

```
PostMethod p = new PostMethod(someurl);
...
NameValuePair[] data = {
    new NameValuePair("name1", "somevalue1"),
    new NameValuePair("var[3][1]", "10")
};
try {
    hc.executeMethod(p);
}
...
```

And that's what I get, when I look at my post in Wireshark:

```
POST /someurl HTTP/1.1
...
type=var&ship%5B3%5D%5B1%5D=10
```

`%5B` means `[`, `%5D`- `]`

So the problem is how I can get square brackets in my post?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the `POST` body should look like. Those square braces must be url encoded. When the client parses the querystring in the `POST` body, it's supposed to url decode those keys and values. Try it with a simple HTML POST form on a web browser and check it with wireshark. You'll see exactly the same thing. There is no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

This is called encoding and this is how data is transferred. However, the service receiving the data will decode this on its end. So you no need to worry  about this.

**You can't send the square brackets as-is** without encoding as they are considered unsafe. Below is the text from [URL RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

> Unsafe:
>
> Characters can be unsafe for a
>   number of reasons.  The space
>   character is unsafe because
>   significant spaces may disappear and
>   insignificant spaces may be introduced
>   when URLs are transcribed or
>   typeset or subjected to the treatment
>   of word-processing programs.    The
>   characters "<" and ">" are unsafe
>   because they are used as the
>   delimiters around URLs in free text;
>   the quote mark (""") is used to
>   delimit URLs in some systems.  The
>   character "#" is unsafe and should
>   always be encoded because it is used
>   in World Wide Web and in other
>   systems to delimit a URL from a
>   fragment/anchor identifier that might 
>   follow it.  The character "%" is
>   unsafe because it is used for
>   encodings of other characters.  Other
>   characters are unsafe because
>   gateways and other transport agents
>   are known to sometimes modify    such
>   characters. These characters are "{",
>   "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",    "[", "]",
>   and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always
>   be encoded within a URL. For
>   example, the character "#" must be
>   encoded within URLs even in    systems
>   that do not normally deal with
>   fragment or anchor    identifiers, so
>   that if the URL is copied into another
>   system that    does use them, it will
>   not be necessary to change the URL
>   encoding.

Comment: yeah yeah, that I understand, BUT, thats what I get, when I wireshark the original post, posted via Firefox, or some any other browser:
name1=somevalue1&var1[3][5]=176&var2[3][6]=261&var3[3][9]=22&var4[3][12]=340... so we don't see here any encoding... are we? :) thats the main problem- i need exacly the same post...

Comment: Can you be more specific on "i need exactly the same post". Its not very clear what are you asking

Comment: Well I need that in my post those brackets should be not encoded and just seen in form '[VALUE]' and not like %5BVALUE%5D (talking about what I see throught wireshark)

Comment: @pushkins: I actually just tested this because I had my doubts. Turns out Firefox *doesn't* encode the square braces as you claimed. But I also tested with Safari and it *does* encode the square braces (as it should!). In any case, it doesn't matter. Your httpclient is behaving correctly and Firefox is not. Is this posting to a PHP script? If so, don't worry about it. The PHP engine will correctly url decode the encoded square braces and all will work as expected.

Comment: @Pangea: I actually verified that Firefox violates the RFC you quoted by not encoding square braces. In the real world, browsers violate RFCs all the time (especially when it comes to lenient parsing of HTML). In any case, it doesn't mean that httpclient should violate it too. httpclient is behaving correctly and according to spec, so @pushkins should simply accept this fact and move on with development.

Comment: Yes it is php script post, and my opera does the same thing as the firefox, and more, when I send post with the encoded braces, i don't get correct answer :) so php engine somehow does not work as expected :)

Comment: @pushkins: If what you say is true then the Safari web browser (and probably Google Chrome too, because they use the same engine) can't post forms with array variables to any PHP site. I'm skeptical... Skeptical enough to test it myself...

Comment: @pushkins: Is the php script on the other end trying to manually parse the `POST` body (like reading it from `php://input` instead of simply using the superglobals like `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`)?

Comment: I'm not sure about that... Another thing, that when I post throught web browser, as an answer I get just one string line, in other case I get whole http page...